# Why aren't my conditional statements working?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working on conditional statements where my float variables are supposed to be in between a range.

If they are above or below the given range then they need to print out whether it's too much or too little.
and if everything within range then it's supposed to print out great! etc

My code works when everything is out of bounds and if everything is in bounds, but if only 1 or 2 things are not within bounds, it still prints out that everything is great alongside that it's too much or too little.

What am I missing?

`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

float salt, pepper, garlic, thyme;


printf("Lets cook!\n");
printf("====================\n");
printf("\n");
printf("Amount of salt added? ");
scanf("%f", &salt);
printf("Amount of pepper added? ");
scanf("%f", &pepper);
printf("Amount of garlic added? ");
scanf("%f", &garlic);
printf("Amount of thyme added? ");
scanf("%f", &thyme);



        if (pepper < 1.5)
                {
                printf("Needs more pepper\n");
                }
        else if(pepper > 3.5)
                {
                printf("Too much pepper!\n");
                }
                
if(salt <5.5)
{
    printf("Needs more salt\n");
}
else if(salt > 13)
{
    printf("Too salty!\n");
}

        if (garlic < 2)
                {
                printf("Needs more garlic\n");
                }
        else if(garlic > 4)
                {
                printf("Too much garlic!\n");
                }

if (thyme < 0.5)
{
     printf("Needs more thyme\n");
}
else if(thyme > 1.25)
    {
         printf("Too much thyme!\n");
    }
    
else
{
    printf("Delicious!\n");
}

        return 0;
}
```

`

When I only have 2 of the conditional statements triggered it still triggers the else:

## Lets cook!

Amount of salt added? 15
Amount of pepper added? 5
Amount of garlic added? 3
Amount of thyme added? 1
Too much pepper!
Too salty!
Delicious

But if all conditional statements are triggered the else doesn't populate:

## Lets cook!

Amount of salt added? 15
Amount of pepper added? 15
Amount of garlic added? 15
Amount of thyme added? 15
Too much pepper!
Too salty!
Too much garlic!
Too much thyme!

And if everything is between the range, the else triggers (like how I want it to):

## Lets cook!

Amount of salt added? 6
Amount of pepper added? 2
Amount of garlic added? 3
Amount of thyme added? 1
Delicious!

How do I get the else to not trigger when only some of them are not within range?

Comment: Note: `if (pepper < 1.5)`  is comparing a `float` with a `double`    This problem happens several times in the posted code.  Suggest that be the first problem to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` in the posted code is related to the last `if ... else if ... else` construct only, not to the other `if ... else if ...`, which are separate statements.

Consider adding a variable counting the in bound cases and changing all those `if`s.

```
int within_range = 0;

if (pepper < 1.5) {
    printf("Needs more pepper\n");
} else if (pepper > 3.5) {
    printf("Too much pepper!\n");
} else {
    ++within_range;
}
             
if (salt < 5.5) {
    printf("Needs more salt\n");
} else if (salt > 13) {
    printf("Too salty!\n");
} else {
    ++within_range;
}

if (garlic < 2) {
    printf("Needs more garlic\n");
} else if (garlic > 4) {
    printf("Too much garlic!\n");
} else {
    ++within_range;
}

if (thyme < 0.5) {
     printf("Needs more thyme\n");
} else if (thyme > 1.25) {
     printf("Too much thyme!\n");
} else {
    ++within_range;
}    

if ( within_range == 4 ) {
    printf("Delicious!\n");
}
```

#### Some alternatives

As [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) commented:

> Instead of counting those in range, I would would count those that are out of range. Then one simply needs `if ( !out_of_range )` at the end i.e. it eliminates the error-prone magical number `4`.

Which leads to something like the following.

```
int out_of_range = 0;

if (pepper < 1.5) {
    printf("Needs more pepper\n");
    ++out_of_range;
} else if (pepper > 3.5) {
    printf("Too much pepper!\n");
    ++out_of_range;
}

// Repeat for all the spices...

if ( !out_of_range ) {
    printf("Delicious!\n");
}
```

---

Repetition of code is error-prone too, so you may consider writing a function.

```
int is_out_of_range( float value
                   , float low, const char *low_str
                   , float high, const char *high_str )
{
  if ( value < low )
  {
    printf("Needs %s\n", low_str);
    return 1;
  }
  if ( value > high )
  {
    printf("Too %s!\n", high_str);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It can then be used like this:

```
if ( 0 ==   is_out_of_range(pepper, 1.5, "more pepper", 3.5,  "much pepper")
          + is_out_of_range(salt,   5.5, "more salt",  13,    "salty")
          + is_out_of_range(garlic, 2,   "more garlic", 4,    "much galic")
          + is_out_of_range(thyme,  0.5, "more thyme",  1.25, "much thyme") )
{
    printf("Delicious!\n");
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize the else was only referencing the the last conditional statement! Thank you for letting me know that

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the "Delicious" comment is only output when both the *thyme* ingredient checks succeed.

One way of implementing this sort of thing is to introduce variables to hold the state of the comparisons.  It's also a technique to write self-documenting code that is quickly understandable by a (perhaps ignorant) reader.

So instead of checking the variable every time, assign the result to a boolean / integer:

```
pepper_low  = ( pepper < 1.5 );
pepper_high = ( pepper > 3.5 );
pepper_ok   = !( pepper_low || pepper_high );
```

Then later on, the code can check `pepper_ok`, e.g.:  `if ( pepper_ok )`.  Which is clear and concise, but at the cost of introducing variables.

This makes your final check for deliciousness something like:

```
if ( salt_ok && pepper_ok && garlic_ok && thyme_ok )
{
    printf("Delicious!\n");
}
```

For a large number of ingredients, discrete variables like this would become unwieldy.  In this case you could use an array of `Ingredient` structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float salt, pepper, garlic, thyme;
    int   salt_low,  pepper_low,  garlic_low,  thyme_low;
    int   salt_high, pepper_high, garlic_high, thyme_high;
    int   salt_ok,   pepper_ok,   garlic_ok,   thyme_ok;

    printf("Lets cook!\n");
    printf("====================\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Amount of salt added? ");
    scanf("%f", &salt);
    printf("Amount of pepper added? ");
    scanf("%f", &pepper);
    printf("Amount of garlic added? ");
    scanf("%f", &garlic);
    printf("Amount of thyme added? ");
    scanf("%f", &thyme);

    salt_low  = ( salt < 5.5 );
    salt_high = ( salt > 13.0 );
    salt_ok   = !( salt_low || salt_high );
    if( salt_low )
    {
        printf("Needs more salt\n");
    }
    else if ( salt_high )
    {
        printf("Too salty!\n");
    }

    pepper_low  = ( pepper < 1.5 );
    pepper_high = ( pepper > 3.5 );
    pepper_ok   = !( pepper_low || pepper_high );
    if ( pepper_low )
    {
        printf("Needs more pepper\n");
    }
    else if ( pepper_high )
    {
        printf("Too much pepper!\n");
    }

               
    // TODO: Repeat for other ingredients

    if ( salt_ok && pepper_ok && garlic_ok && thyme_ok )
    {
        printf("Delicious!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```